# Eigen library setup in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I have a project file structure like this:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── deps
│   ├── cxxtest
│   └── eigen
├── main.cpp
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── hello_world.cpp
```

and the two CMakeLists.txt files and two .cpp files are

[image]

So my question is why I have to put the Eigen library setup in the top level of CMakeLists.txt file as follow to make the top level .cpp file work, i.e., finding the Eigen/Dense header, but the lower level of .cpp will always work no matter if both the top and the lower levels of CMakeLists.txt files have the following setup or not?

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
target_link_libraries(proj Eigen3::Eigen)
```

Comment: Isn't it that you have a system wide installation of Eigen? I don't think that the `find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)` find the Eigen files in your `deps` directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the actual code in your question post as text! Do not post *images* of the code.

Comment: @arghol, I tried to wipe out the build folder and ran "cmake .." and "make" again. The lower level.cpp file also did not work anymore (cannot find the header file). So I had to add the eigen setup for this lower level project. So I now really get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use the local Eigen library in your project directory tree, i.e. `deps/eigen`. The easiest way to do this is to just add the Eigen subdirectory as normal, using `add_subdirectory`. You also might need to change the target library from `Eigen3::Eigen` to `eigen`. The main `CMakeLists.txt` then looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(PROJECT)

add_subdirectory(deps/eigen)
add_subdirectory(tests)

set(SRC_LIST main.cpp)
add_executable(proj ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(proj eigen)
```

Also, in order to make the unit test `hello_world.cpp` work you need to add the linking to the Eigen library in the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `tests` directory, i.e.:

```
target_link_libraries(hello_world eigen)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I only need to add "add_subdirectory(deps/eigen)" to the main CMakeLists.txt? If so, could you please explain why?  Another question is how to know where a header file is included from when precompile a project especially if the build system is generated by CMake? Thank you

Comment: You only need `add_subdirectory(deps/eigen)` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` since other `CMakeLists.txt` "inherits" this dependency. Every (correctly configured) CMake based library or module exports its include directories, you only need to link it to your application or library (via `target_add_libraries`) in order to get the compiler to search the right directories for header files.

Comment: Thank you very much. All make sense but I still have a question about `target_link_libraries(hello_world eigen)`. what is `eigen` in this sentence? It should be a library file, right? But I did not find any file in `deps/eigen` and it all subdirectories. So I got confused about what `eigen` is